# Favorite tag highlightings on request page

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

On MSO, I have [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tagged as one of my favorites. There is a feature request page, labeled as "reqs." The tab is to the left of the active tab.

[image: Bugs|Reqs|Active]

When I go over to that page, every single question is highlighted, because I have [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) as one of my favorite tags. I think that this is a little redundant. So I am proposing that it work similar to the page of a specific tag, where if I am on the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag page, none of them are highlighted, unless I have another favorite tag on one of the questions.

For clarification, the only other tags I have as favorite are [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) and [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Comment: Do you mean the featured page? It is not for [meta-tag:feature-request] - it is for questions with bounties on them.

Comment: No. In the picture, the reqs page is what I'm talking about

Comment: @Oded I had no idea such tab exists either until very recently as well, it's only here on Meta.

Comment: Seems pretty pointless to have a tab for such things.